# Crystal behavior with variables assignement

Tags: behavior, crystal-lang

I create this class:

```
1.  class Component
2.
3.    getter :content, :htm_options, :options
3.
4.    @html_options : Hash(Symbol | String, Symbol | String)
5.    @options      : Hash(Symbol | String, Symbol | String)
6.    @content      : String
7.
8.    def initialize(c = nil, o = nil, h = nil, block = nil)
9.      if false #!block.nil?
10.       @html_options = o unless o.nil? 
11.       @options      = c unless c.nil?
12.       context  = eval("self", block.binding)
13.       @content = context.capture(&block)
14.     else
15.       if c.is_a?(Hash)
16.         @html_options = o unless o.nil? 
17.         @options      = c unless c.nil?
18.       else
19.         @html_options = h unless h.nil? 
20.         @options      = o unless o.nil? 
21.         @content      = c unless c.nil? 
22.        end
23.     end
24.   end
25. end  

Component.new("My text")
```

I have an error :

```
in src/ui_bibz/ui/core/component.cr:11: instance variable '@options' of Component must be Hash(String | Symbol, String | Symbol), not String
@options = c unless c.nil?
```

I don't understand this behavior because I do not pass in the if condition. I'd like assign `@htm_options, @options, @content` according to several conditions.
Is it possible to declare a variable that has already been declared once?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid the compiler is sometimes not smart enough to detect which paths are taken and which are not, when checking for types. So, in line 11, the compiler sees that you are attempting to assign a String to a variable previously defined as a Hash, and fails.

As for your question, I'm afraid it is not possible to re-declare an instance variable. If you do want `@options` to hold both a String or a Hash, you can declare it to be a Union of Hash and String.

Comment: It's annoying :( Thanks

Comment: Because after, i have a method which merge @options with a Hash. But compiler alert me with an error: `Couldn't find overloads for these types: Hash(Symbol, Symbol)#merge(other : String)`. It's normal because i define @options like an union of Hash and String. There's no solution !! :(

Comment: There is always a solution or hack that will work, but Crystal is statically typed, and using unions of totally different types will usually end up being very annoying. Maybe you can rethink your API so options is always a `Hash(String, String)` for example?

Comment: It's more restrictive and at the same time safer, as it will prevent you from making any type mistakes. Do not think of Crystal as a faster-Ruby: being statically typed makes a big difference in how you structure your code.

Comment: @SantiagoPalladino Yeah I'm learning that the hard way.  Also that Crystal still isn't ready for primetime.  Pretty much any array or complex Hash used in any substantial ruby program filled with multiple types has to be thrown out if its to be converted over to crystal...  (Think of Rails constant symbol => string value pairing almost everywhere....)  I've found this to kill the easy chances of converting over even the simplest of scripts sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal is typed and this is a good thing, but for my case, i'd like to redefine my variables. My code works like a "[link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)" in ruby. A component must be write in different ways. Sometimes, content will be filled by variable, sometimes by block. Initialize method will be filled by different ways. There's a way to redefined variables by macro or by an other solution?

```
class Component < UiBibz::Ui::Base

  getter :content, :htm_options, :options

  def initialize(c = nil, o = nil, h = nil, block = nil)
    if !block.nil?
      html_opts, opts = o, c
      context  = eval("self", block.binding)
      @content = context.capture(&block)
    else
      if c.is_a?(Hash)
        html_opts, opts = o, c
      else
        html_opts, opts, cont = h, o, c
      end
    end
    @html_options = html_opts || {} of Symbol => Symbol | String
    @options      = opts      || {} of Symbol => Symbol | String
    @content      = content
  end
end 

# 1 way
Component.new("My content", { :option_1 => true }, { :class => "red" })  

# 2 way
Component.new({ :option_1 => true }, { :class => "red" }) do
  "My content"
end
```

Error:

```
in src/ui_bibz/ui/core/component.cr: instance variable '@options' of Component must be Hash(Symbol, String | Symbol), not (Hash(Symbol, String | Symbol) | String)
@options = opts || {} of Symbol => Symbol | String
```

Comment: Anyone ? please :(

Comment: I found my answer ! https://blog.codeship.com/crystal-from-a-rubyists-perspective/ 
i must override initialize method.